# QlikSense - REST API chain call - script

Tags: rest, api, qliksense

I need to integrate data in my Qlik Sense project using cloud REST api. I need to call a chain of API as I firstly need the Token

Basically:
1) "Token" REST passing user+psw getting token 
2) "API2" REST passing token received from 1 in the BODY

I successfully created the script for generate the code:

```
RestConnectorMasterTable:
SQL SELECT 
    "token",
    "__KEY_root"
FROM JSON (wrap on) "root" PK "__KEY_root"
WITH CONNECTION(BODY "$(vRequestBody)");


[root]:
LOAD    [token] AS [token]
RESIDENT RestConnectorMasterTable
WHERE NOT IsNull([__KEY_root]);

DROP TABLE RestConnectorMasterTable;
```

My problem is that I don't uderstand how to use [token] as a variable to pass in the 2 call.
If I use:

```
let tokenizer = [token]
```

I does not work.
Any idea?
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i undestand well your question, you need to get a token from the first call to use it in the second call.

the simple way is to use lookup function to get your token :

```
let validToken = lookup('token', '__KEY_root', 1 ,'root');
```

then in your second request

```
'SELECT 
    "_scroll_id",
    "__KEY_root",
    (SELECT 
        "__FK_hits",
        (SELECT 
            (SELECT              
                $(Fields)                 
            FROM "_source" FK "__FK__source")
        FROM "hits" PK "__KEY_hits_u0" FK "__FK_hits_u0")
    FROM "hits" PK "__KEY_hits" FK "__FK_hits")
    FROM JSON (wrap on) "root" PK "__KEY_root"
    WITH CONNECTION(
                Url "$(url)",
                BODY "$(validToken)"
    )';
```